# AWS Glue read from RDS database that's in VPC

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-glue

I have an RDS database that is sitting in a VPC. My ultimate goal is to run a nightly job that takes the data from RDS and stores it in Redshift. I am currently doing this using Glue and Glue connections. I am able to write to RDS/Redshift using connections with the following line:

```
datasource2 = DynamicFrame.fromDF(dfFinal, glueContext, "scans")

output = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(frame = datasource2, catalog_connection = "MPtest", connection_options = {"database" : "app", "dbtable" : "scans"})
```

Where dfFinal is my final data frame after a bunch of transformations that are not essential to this post. That code works fine, however I would like to modify it so I could read a table from RDS into a data frame.

Since the RDS database is in a VPC, I would like to use the `catalog_connection` parameter, but the `DynamicFrameReader` class has no `from_jdbc_conf` method and thus no obvious way to use my glue connection.

I have seen posts that say you could use a method like this:

```
url = "jdbc:postgresql://host/dbName"
properties = {
"user" : "user",
"password" : "password"
}
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=url, table="table", properties=properties)
```

But when I try that it times out because it's not a publicly accessible database. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with using Glue connections.

1. Define Glue connection of Type JDBC for your Postgres instance

   ```
   Type    JDBC

   JDBC URL    jdbc:postgresql://<RDS ip>:<RDS port>/<database_name>

   VPC Id  <VPC of RDS instance>

   Subnet  <subnet of RDS instance>

   Security groups <Security Group allowed to connect to RDS>
   ```
2. Edit Glue Job, and select the Glue Connection so it appears under "Required Connections"
3. Create connections options dictionary as

```
options = {'url': connection.jdbc_url,

           'user': connection.username,

           'password': connection.password,

           'dbtable': table
}
```

4. Use the options dictionary in the below to create a Dynamic frame to read from the table

```
table_ddf = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(

        connection_type='postgresql',

        connection_options=options,

        transformation_ctx=transformation_ctx
)
```